# How to know specific TF-IDF value of a word?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf

How can I know the value of a specific word using the TfidfVectorizer function?
For example, my code is:

```
docs = []
docs.append("this is sentence number one")
docs.append("this is sentence number two")
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(norm='l2',min_df=0, use_idf=True, smooth_idf=True, stop_words='english', sublinear_tf=True)
sklearn_representation = vectorizer.fit_transform(docs)
```

Now, how can I know the TF-IDF value of "sentence" in the sentence 2 (docs[1])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `vectorizer`'s `vocabulary_` attribute, which is a mapping of terms to feature indices.

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
>>> docs = []
>>> docs.append("this is sentence number one")
>>> docs.append("this is sentence number two")
>>> vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(norm='l2',min_df=0, use_idf=True, smooth_idf=True, stop_words='english', sublinear_tf=True)
>>> x = vectorizer.fit_transform(docs)
>>> x.todense()
matrix([[ 0.70710678,  0.70710678],
        [ 0.70710678,  0.70710678]])
>>> vectorizer.vocabulary_['sentence']
1
>>> c = vectorizer.vocabulary_['sentence']
>>> x[:,c]
<2x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> x[:,c].todense()
matrix([[ 0.70710678],
        [ 0.70710678]])
```

Comment: what did `vectorizer.vocabulary_['sentence']` do?
and how can I only get one value? only the TF-IDF value for that word in a particular document

Comment: @Skinish As I explained, the `vocabulary_` attribute is a mapping (i.e. a `dict`) of terms to feature indices. In your X matrix, columns correspond to features and rows to documents. You have the column, so choose your corresponding row if you want only 1 row. `x[:, c]` chooses *all* rows. If you wanted the first, for example, you could have done `x[0, c]`

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!